# Is there a way for a chrome extension to always listen?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I've built a chrome extension that keeps track of your visited sites by getting their URLs. The problem is, it only receives the URL of the page when the extension is opened/clicked. How can I make it so it'll "listen" to the sites I visit at all times?

I tried to fix it by making it get the URL on site onload, but I think what's happening is that it listens on the EXTENSION onload:

```js
window.onload = function () {


  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    d = document;
    f = document.getElementById("history");

    var i = d.createElement('li');
    i.innerHTML = tab.url;
    f.appendChild(i);
    d.body.appendChild(f);


    localStorage.setItem("pastVisits", f.innerHTML);



  });


  try { // trycatch because what if there's no history to pull?
    document.getElementById("history").innerHTML += localStorage.getItem("pastVisits");
  } catch (error) {
    // do nothing...
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;

    background-color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User Locations</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="history">

    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Added the snippet even though it doesn't work in the snippet for some reason (It does work in the extension though). Here's an image of it: [image]

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in a content or background script? And: isn't this just replicating browser history?

Comment: @Andy It's a part of the extension. Yes, this is just replicating the browser history but I wanted to challenge myself to see if I could do it myself.

Comment: That's good. You should realise that `getSelected` has been deprecated and you should be using [`query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query) instead. That will return an object and you can pick the URL from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will add ["history" permission](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history).

```
// manifest.json

{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "history"
  ],
  ...
}
```

And then, use

```
// background.js

chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(
  result => console.log(result)
)
```

"Fired when a URL is visited, providing the HistoryItem data for that URL. This event fires before the page has loaded."